# How to create horizontal recycleview with two rows and dynamic item width

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to create a layout like below image, I tried [flowLayout](https://github.com/nex3z/FlowLayout) with 2 rows, but when I put it in HorizontalScroll it be just one row.
Also I tried Recycleview with GridLayoutManager but all columns will be same width.
How I can create some thing like below image?

[image]

**Answer**: I used below code and it solved my problem.

```
 new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
```

Comment: Maybe [flexbox-layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) can help you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55630261/8194166 Try this answer

Comment: set android:orientation="horizontal", app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager" & app:spanCount="2" in android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

Comment: Just like this <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:spanCount="2"
                app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager" />